# Run Sed command inside Awk split(for loop)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, sh

Pardon my English, please.

I'm new to shell script and I'm trying to run the sed replace command for each element inside the for loop after split a string using awk

```
# !/bin/sh
SCRIPT_DIR=`pwd`
TEXT_FIELD=$SCRIPT_DIR/Field/textField

FIELDS="code-text name-text"
echo "$FIELD" | awk '{len = split($0,t," ") 
for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
    "sed -i 's/inputPlaceholder/t[i]/g' $TEXT_FIELD"
} }'
```

When I run it : `$ sh code_sample.sh`
It's not throw error but not working neither.

Can you help me. I'm most grateful.

---

**EDIT**

My goal is to read `code-text name-text` into `array[1] = "code-text"`, `array[2] = "name-text"`.

Then the for loop will read one by one and replace each item to the `inputPlaceholder` string in the given file.

Example:

Input: FILED="code-text name-text"

Output (in the file): text->create("inputPlaceholder") becomes text->create("code-text") and save as code.txt and with the same logic save name-text to name.txt.

Comment: Not working how? Give example of input, expected vs actual outputs. Your English is fine by the way, so you are pardoned.

Comment: No. A shell is an environment from which to call tools. Awk is a tool for processing text. Guess which one it's appropriate to call sed from (hint: it's not awk!). [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do whatever it is you are trying to do the right way (which will not involve awk calling sed!).

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: how's your logic work?  When you replace all "inputPlaceholder" instances with the first field "code-text" what do you expect the next replacement to be?

Comment: It's still very unclear what you want to do. Please read [ask] and then simply post a sample of your input and output files with the text you are interested in in-context.

Comment: 1. What should happen if the file contains `inputPlaceholder inputPlaceholder inputPlaceholder`. 2. Should both code.txt and name.txt be created from the same input file?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `system("sed ....")` call, but it sounds like a terrible idea. You'd have to make sure that the replacement text is safe to use in sed expression for example, or the command would fail for some inputs.

Also you'll have to escape the quote characters, because by writing `sed -i '...` you're breaking out of the awk text quoting.

If you're actually doing text processing like this, I'd recommend something more advanced than sh. Python, Perl, Ruby, and many others will do this just fine.

If you want some specific examples, you'll have to say what do you expect the script to do - the current example is badly broken and I'm not sure what the expected input/output/action is.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take  a look. Thank you.

Comment: Because most of  main control of my system using sh file such as start.sh,stop.sh. So I was thinking to use sh for convenience.

Comment: @RobustTran You're fine using shell to call awk and then using awk to do the text processing. That's what both tools were designed to do and do very well.

Comment: @EdMorton There are limitations on what you can do and how easy however. At some point it may be worth upgrading the language just to avoid the shell's escaping hell.

Comment: @viraptor sorry but there is no "escaping hell". Remember, we are talking about manipulating text, nothing else.

Comment: @EdMorton : yeah standard english text with ample amount of ampersands `&` in it - not remembering to escape those in the replacement regex then one can watch the output text grow at geometric rates.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Do you need to use `awk`, or are you trying to solve this problem:

> I have a list of patterns that look like `foobar-text`, and a data file in which the string `inputPlaceholder` appears. For each pattern, I want to replace every occurrence of `inputPlaceholder` in the data file with the pattern, then store the result in a new file called `foobar.txt`. The output filename is generated from the pattern by replacing the hyphen with a dot, and changing `text` to `txt`, so `foobar-txt` will become `foobar.txt`.

If that's the problem you need to solve, here's a solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
readonly FIELDS="code-text name-text"
readonly TEXT_FIELD="data.txt"

for pattern in ${FIELDS}; do
  # Replace hyphen with dot.
  file=$(echo ${pattern} | sed -e 's/-/./' -e 's/text/txt/')
  sed "s/inputPlaceholder/${pattern}/g" "${TEXT_FIELD}" > "${file}"
done
```

---

Example:

**Input: `data.txt`**

```
This is the data file.
The pattern text->create("inputPlaceholder") will be replaced and saved in a file.
This line also contains the pattern text->create("inputPlaceholder").
But this line is unchanged.
```

**Output: `code.txt`:**

```
This is the data file.
The pattern text->create("code-text") will be replaced and saved in a file.
This line also contains the pattern text->create("code-text").
But this line is unchanged.
```

**Output: `name.txt`:**

```
This is the data file.
The pattern text->create("name-text") will be replaced and saved in a file.
This line also contains the pattern text->create("name-text").
But this line is unchanged.
```